# Power wire-to-board connector identification

Tags: connector, eaglecad

I am laying out my PCB and I would like to include this power connector in the layout. I am unable to identify the connector based on the its locking ability and layout. It could even be a common one and I am just missing something.

[image: Blue connector]

[image: Flat pins]

Comment: Do you want to purchase a connector, or just need a footprint to place on the PC board?  If you just need a footprint, it will be much easier and faster to make the footprint yourself than to try to find a ready-made footprint.  If you do any amount of PC layout, you _will_ need to make some of your own footprints, so you may as well learn how now.

Comment: I am trying to identiy the connector so I can pinpoint a datasheet with exact measurements to use if avaliable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this connector for your application?

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0428192223/WM9796-ND/3310025

The power connector in your photo looks a lot like the ATX series power connectors.